# How to upload file from phone and send it as FormData Ionic 4

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm using Ionic trying to use chooser plugin to chose file from phone, transform the URI to a File and send it as FormData. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize FormData object by creating an instance from new FormData interface as given below. 
**const formData = new FormData()**

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('firstname', this.firstname);
    formData.append('lastname', this.lastname);
    formData.append('email' , this.email);
    formData.append('phone' , this.phone);
    formData.append('experience' , this.experience);
    formData.append('userId' , this.userInfo.user.id);
```